# Python: Ordering list of words with chosen alphabetical order

Tags: python, alphabet

I am trying to create a program that orders a list of words with my choice of alphabetical order, but I am a little confused with how to begin.

For instance, if the chosen alphabetical order was: UVWXYZNOPQRSTHIJKLMABCDEFG
Then words would be sorted in this order:

- WHATEVER
- ZONE
- HOW
- HOWEVER
- HILL
- ANY
- ANTLER
- COW

Answer (score 3):

You can use a sort key that maps letters to a list of integers, the integers being in order in which to sort:

```
sort_key = {l: i for i, l in enumerate('UVWXYZNOPQRSTHIJKLMABCDEFG')}
sorted_words = sorted(words, key=lambda w: [sort_key[l] for l in w])
```

Lists are ordered lexicographically, that is, by comparing the elements of two lists one by one until a differing element is found, which then determines the order. For the words `'ANTLER'` and `'ANY'` are mapped to `[19, 6, 12, 17, 23, 10]` and `[19, 6, 4]`, respectively, so `'ANY'` will be listed first as `4 < 10`.

Demo:

```
>>> words = ['ANTLER', 'ANY', 'COW', 'HILL', 'HOW', 'HOWEVER', 'WHATEVER', 'ZONE']
>>> sort_key = {l: i for i, l in enumerate('UVWXYZNOPQRSTHIJKLMABCDEFG')}
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda w: [sort_key[l] for l in w])
['WHATEVER', 'ZONE', 'HOW', 'HOWEVER', 'HILL', 'ANY', 'ANTLER', 'COW']
```